# Trigger function when ngIf turns true to set focus on input which gets revealed

Tags: javascript, angular

I´m currently trying to set the cursors focus on a specific input field, which is just displayed when the surrounding ngIf is true.
The html code looks something like this:

```
<div>
    <button (click)="showFirst = !showFirst">Toogle</button>
    <div *ngIf="showFirst">
        <!-- Some content -->
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!showFirst">
        <input type="text" #myInput>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my components JS I´m trying to get the ElementRef but it returns `undefined` all the time because I try to fetch it before it was initialized.
So the qustion is:

**How is it possible to set the focus on the input field after `showFirst` becomes `false` and the input gets visible?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the focus in the `AfterViewChecked` lifecycle hook, as shown in [**this plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ShjODCkAJW8Q2D1s5dQh?p=preview). I added a check to make sure that the focus is set only when the input element becomes visible, not every time `AfterViewChecked` is triggered.

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewChecked, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

export class MyComponent implements AfterViewChecked {

  @ViewChild("myInput") private myInput: ElementRef;

  public showFirst = true;
  private prevShowFirst = true;

  public ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    if (!this.showFirst && this.prevShowFirst) {
      this.myInput.nativeElement.focus();
    }
    this.prevShowFirst = this.showFirst;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the autofocus attribute.
Or just add a setFocus at the end of (click) if showFirst is false

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get the ElementRef inside the OnChanges life cycle hook. Something like:

```
OnChanges(): void {
  if (!this.showFirst) {
    // check ElementRef
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular has a lifecycle hook `ngAfterViewChecked` which is called after every check of a component's view.

Once your view is changed this lifecycle hook will be called and here you can write the logic for focusing.

```
ngAfterViewChecked(){
  // you logic for focusing or check ElementRef.
}
```